# Дек на основе сегментированного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

Подскажите , как сделать конструктор с указанным количеством элементов и значением для заполнения, равным T() по умолчанию, и общую структуру.
У меня есть директория указателей на блоки с данными , сам блок данных (массив фиксированного размера),количество элементов фактически использованных в первом и последнем блоках, индексы крайних использованных в директории блоков с каждой из сторон. Выходит блоки начинают выделяться в середине директории, чтобы оставить место для новых блоков, которые могут появиться при вставке элементов с любой из сторон дека , и как это все преобразовать в конструкторе. Вот конструктор принимает размер , и как он его распределяет по директории , что б блоки эти выделялись и заполнялись значениями? Спасибо)

@Majestio @Vlad from Moscow

```
template< typename T >
class MyDeque
{
private:

    //Количество ячеек в массиве - директории
    int directorySize[5];
    // Количество ячеек в каждом блоке данных
    int datablock[16];
    // Массив-директория: указатели на блоки данных
    int ** directory;
    // Индексы верхней и нижней позиции из занятых ячеек в директории
    int frontBlockIndex, backBlockIndex;
    // Количество занятых элементов в первом и последнем блоках
    int frontUsed, backUsed;

    int size;
public:
    MyDeque();
    MyDeque( int Size, const T& value);
    int getSize();
    bool empty();
};

template< typename T >
MyDeque< T >::MyDeque()
{
    size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    directory[5] = nullptr; // не уверен что верно
}
template< typename T >
MyDeque< T >::MyDeque(int Size, const T& value)
{
.......................
}
```

Вот что у меня есть, использовать STL нельзя , и мне непонятно как сделать конструктор , как я писал выше , не пойму как выделять блоки в середине директории , и как их заполнять , еще не уверен в дефолтном конструкторе

Comment: Вам виднее, как сделать конструктор. Это же ваш класс, не так ли?:)

Comment: я не пойму алгоритм, принцип распределения , как выделять блоки в середине и тд

Comment: Читайте первоисточник, на основе которого вы собираетесь сделать программу.

Comment: очень помогли , спасибо (нет)

Comment: Дело в том, что вопрос слишком общий. Вы не привели никакого объявления класса и, вообще, ни строчки кода. Поэтому если вопрос идет об алгоритме, то читайте литературу по этому алгоритму. А абстрактно говорить, как у вас должен быть определен конструктор, это несерьезно, так как определения конструктора зависит от класса и его поведения.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: это  и все чтоли?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос действительно весьма размытый. Предлагаю сперва его самостоятельно "причесать" по используемым терминам и сущностям. Говорят "в правильно заданном вопросе - содержится 50% правильного ответа"

Ну а по тому, что есть - в виде предположений ...

1. Раз вопрос помечен тегом "с++", логично предположить использование возможностей самого "с++" (как надмножества Си) и/или STL.
2. Если нужно реализовать "Дек на основе сегментированного массива" на основе STL, читаем описание [std::deque](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque) и [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). Пытаемся реализовать свой аллокатор.
3. Если нужно реализовать "Дек на основе сегментированного массива" без использования STL, ищем и читаем в сети про "[placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)".

Остается незактытым вопрос "политики размещения" элементов с помощью указанных выше аллокаторов или placement new...

> Выходит блоки начинают выделяться в середине директории, чтобы оставить место для новых блоков

А это уже как запрограммировать. Тем не менее, возможно понадобится:

- Размер "того", где будем выделять
- Список нераспределенных блоков "там"
- Механизм решения вопроса "а что делать, если нераспределенные блоки закончились?"

Реализация "Списка нераспределенных блоков" напрямую зависит от, скажем так, прогноза использования. В STL разные контейнеры ведут себя по разному (по скорости) при доступе, вставке, удалению, добавлению. Тут уже должно быть виднее разработчику по условиям реальной задачи - какой вид контейнеров для этого использовать.

Как-то вот так. Каков вопрос - таков ответ :)

Comment: я дополнил вопрос